# How to modify a GET request to trigger a file attachment response (legitimately)?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, http-headers

I have a Django project that uses the python chess module to show a chess board in the main view. It defaults to a blank board:

views.py

```
import chess, chess.pgn

def index(request, pgn_slug=None):
    board = chess.Board()
    game = chess.pgn.Game.from_board(board)
    game.headers["DrawOffered"] = "False"
```

The main index function catches AJAX requests and serves responses:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

if request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
    ...
    return JsonResponse(response_obj)
```

Or it will render the page:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
else:
    html = get_html(game, board)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

I want one elif to return a .txt attachment based on the python-chess [game writing functions](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pgn.html#writing). How do I achieve this with well-formed requests and responses? Django seems to have a [dedicated response object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects) for this kind of thing but I can't quite put two and two together. Something like this maybe?:

```
from django.http import FileResponse
elif request._____ == 'download': # what could mark the request?
    file_name = 'foo.txt'
    file = open(filename, 'wt')
    file.write(str(game))
    return FileResponse(file, as_attachment=True,
        filename=file_name)
```

The request is triggered by a button on the same page and a JavaScript function and would either call up the URL of the window or one that gets dynamically passed to the function from AJAX:

```
<script>
function downloadPGN(URL) { 
    if (URL === undefined) { 
        URL = window.location.href 
    }
    // ... GET request with modified headers? 
</script>
<button type="button" id="downloadButton" 
    onClick="downloadPGN()">↓</button>
```

I realize my question is similar to a few others but the solutions seemed a decade old and very convoluted for what strikes me as a fairly simple problem. I feel as though I'm missing some small, vital detail. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'd like to leave the main page view intact when processing this request -- possibly by spawning a new window and then closing?

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the html download attribute produces different GET headers. Uncertain of portability but this worked to separate GET from GET-with-download requests on my local system.

```
fetch = request.headers.get('Sec-Fetch-Site')
dest = request.headers.get('Sec-Fetch-Dest')
if fetch == 'same-origin' and dest == 'empty':
    disp = 'attachment; filename="foo.txt"'
    return HttpResponse(get_download(game), headers={
        'Content-Disposition': disp })
else: 
    html = get_html(request.path, game, board)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```